# How to remotely access Kibana in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am currently trying to make my Kibana dashboard remotely accessible via the browser. So, a user can monitor index and run scripts in a remote manner. As background, my elastic is currently ran on Windows server and I could successfully set 'elastic uri search' (e.g. http://[IP_ADDRESS]:9200) remotely accessible by updating **elasticsearch.yml** and opening the port **9200**. For this reason, I took similar actions to remotely access Kibana, updating **kibana.yml** and opening the port **5601**, but I couldn't remotely access kibana on the browser from my local machine. It throws *ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT* on the browser. See attributes that I have updated for kibana.yml:

```
server.port: "5601"
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

Comment: The solution was to disable the block rule in windows firewall settings.

Answer (score 6):

You need to configure the file `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` as root:
Uncomment the lines:

**server.port: 5601**

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601
```

**server.host: "0.0.0.0"**

```
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

**elasticsearch.hosts**

Change the `<your-elastic-server-ip>` to your elastic search server IP, something like **192.168.1.XX**

```
# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://<your-elastic-server-ip>:9200"]
```

And check the ports on your firewall:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Output:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens33
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ftp ssh
  ports: 10000/tcp 3306/tcp 9200/tcp 5601/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

If you don't see the ports **9200/tcp 5601/tcp** opened then do the following command as sudo:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 9200/tcp
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 5601/tcp
```

Comment: What if my elasticsearch api is behind a reverse proxy server in a context (URI) path like `"http://<my-elastic-server-ip>:80/elasticsearch"`? The elasticsearch.hosts configuration does not seem to work in this case!

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps to connect remote Elasticsearch on AWS EC2 to my local kibana.

Backup your original .yml files

`sudo cp /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml elasticsearch.yml.bk`

`sudo cp /etc/kibana/kibana.yml kibana.yml.bk`

1. Edit security groups and add a new rule - custom TCP with port 9200 accessible via your public IP v4.
2. ssh to your server and tweak ufw to allow your ip over 9200 `sudo ufw allow from <your public v4 IP> to any port 9200`
3. edit elasticsearch.yml to add `network.host: 0.0.0.0`
   `discovery.type: single-node` [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534228/cant-access-my-elasticsearch-through-public-ip-in-ec2-instance)
4. on your local machine edit kibana.yml and add `elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://34.103.134.135:9200"]`
5. go to `http://localhost:5601/` you should see your remote index under Discover> index management.
   `

Comment: I would advise against opening up your Elasticsearch to the public internet like that.  A better setup would involve creating an SSH tunnel or even a reverse proxy to access Elasticsearch.  Even a simple ssh -L "9200:localhost:9200" user@cloudserver would be better if you needed to tweak it without leaving it open like that.