# Can't access my elasticsearch through public IP in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, networking, amazon-ec2

I have deployed elasticsearch(7.3 version) service on my EC2 instance.

- After installing when I did
  `curl localhost:9200`it gave me correct response but when I accessed the same service by hitting request:`http://{{public-ip-address-ec2-instance}}:9200`

It is giving error as :

**This site can’t be reached : {{public-ip-address-ec2-instance}} connection refused.**

- I have configured security group of EC2 instance by allowing inbound traffic on custom TCP which is set to default elastic search port `9200` and is open to `0.0.0.0/0`.

Currently I haven't modified `elasticsearch.yml` and it has default values only.

So **how can I access elasticsearch through public IP of EC2 instance?**
**Do I need to make any changes in elasticsearch configuration file?**

Comment: Is your instance exposed to the Internet? You need an IGW attachment for your subnet to be able publicly access the machine.

Comment: Yes it is exposed to Internet.

Comment: This seems like a connectivity issue. Can you test the connectivity using `telnet` or `nc` to the specific IP on 9200 and verify the results?

Comment: I am able to ping this EC2 instance from my localhost by allowing through ICMP port. Additionally, I have other services as well (like ember) that is running on this EC2 instance and these other services I am able to access through public IP address of EC2 instance.

Comment: You need to set `network.host` in your `elasticsearch.yml` config file. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397922/elasticsearch-instance-not-reachable-from-outside-the-server-azure-windows-201/36398332#36398332)

Comment: @Val After changing elasticsearch.yml to above mentioned network host and restarting service I got error as:  ` bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks. ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed`

Comment: @Val  I resolved this error by adding discovery.type: single-node and its working fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the solution was simply to modify the following settings in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: single-node
```

Note: The second setting is only necessary if you have a single node.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for this answer :) **BE CAREFUL**: setting `cluster.initial_master_nodes: ubuntu.local` instead of `discovery.type: single-node` can make ES (from your EC2 instance) unreachable (no idea why tho)