# Not able to run Elasticsearch in docker on amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to run elasticsearch 7.7 in docker container using t2.medium instance and went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534228/cant-access-my-elasticsearch-through-public-ip-in-ec2-instance) SO question and [official ES docs on installing ES using docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) but even after giving `discovery.type: single-node` its not bypassing the bootstrap checks mentioned in several posts.

My `elasticsearch.yml` file

```
cluster.name: scanner
node.name: node-1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: single-node
cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1 // tried explicitly giving this but no luck
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
COPY elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
USER root
RUN chmod go-w /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
RUN chown root:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
USER elasticsearch
```

And this is how I am building and running the image.

```
docker build -t es:latest .
docker run --ulimit nofile=65535:65535 -p 9200:9200 es:latest
```

And relevant error logs

> 75", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address,
>   enforcing bootstrap checks" } ERROR: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534228/cant-access-my-elasticsearch-through-public-ip-in-ec2-instance) bootstrap checks failed [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534228/cant-access-my-elasticsearch-through-public-ip-in-ec2-instance):
>   the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at
>   least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers,
>   cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured ERROR: Elasticsearch
>   did not exit normally - check the logs at
>   /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/docker-cluster.log

Comment: let me know if I need to provide any additional info ?

Comment: Try adding transport.host: localhost to the elasticsearch.yml file. Taken from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19987#issuecomment-298597068

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj thanks tried but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

### Elasticsearch in a single node

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=vibhuvi-node
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=vibhuvi-es-data-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - vibhuviesdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge  
volumes:
  vibhuviesdata:
    driver: local
```

### Run

`docker-compose up -d`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was not looking for docker-compose way.